# Access an array value within an object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm new to PHP and am trying to access the value of "contactId" from the following:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) { 
    ["contacts"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (18) { 

            ["email"]=> string(24) "joewilliams@icontact.com" 
            ["firstName"]=> string(3) "Joe" 
            ["lastName"]=> string(8) "Williams" 
            ["prefix"]=> string(3) "Mr." 
            ["suffix"]=> string(3) "Jr." 
            ["fax"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["phone"]=> string(10) "8668039462" 
            ["street"]=> string(21) "2365 Meridian Parkway" 
            ["street2"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["city"]=> string(6) "Durham" 
            ["state"]=> string(2) "NC" 
            ["postalCode"]=> string(5) "27713" 
            ["createDate"]=> string(19) "2013-03-30 21:22:28" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "normal" 
            ["bounceCount"]=> NULL 
            ["contactId"]=> string(8) "67295434" 
        } 
    } 
    ["limit"]=> int(20) 
    ["offset"]=> int(0) 
    ["total"]=> int(1) 
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of contactId?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not arrays, but an object containing an array containing an object.  PHP object access syntax is with `->`

```
$variableName->contacts[0]->contactId
```

Comment: Got it - NOW I see what's going on... duh. Thanks for your fast help. Awesome.